# Duplicate ID errors in w3c validators

Tags: duplicates

I recently installed and set up maximenuck on my Joomla 3.1.5 website. I'm getting duplicate ID errors in w3c validators.

Line 1018, Column 64: Duplicate ID dropdown.

```
      <div class="maximenuckh" id="dropdown" style="z-index:10;">
```

Line 880, Column 64: The first occurrence of ID dropdown was here.

```
      <div class="maximenuckh" id="dropdown" style="z-index:10;">
```

I spoke to the programmer of maximenus and he said "this seems to be related to the mobile system (from bootstrap ?) that loads the menu 2x in the HTML code. This is really not a good idea, because of this error but also because you will have all the links 2x in your page. Not sure if google and other robots really like this ..."

He also told me it was a template error and he didn't know how to fix it.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these errors. The website is www.teach-this.com. I'm using a favthemes template.

Thanks in advance

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two HTML elements which share the same ID attribute, an ID attribute must be unique.

**ID attribute: Syntax**

```
<element id="id">
```

**ID attribute: Definition**

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be **unique**     within the HTML document).

see also [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)